# auto footer height with page height

Tags: css

i have a page with "7px header","540px content" and footer
i want footer height depend on page height change and page no scroll . 
example

```
if page height 700px;
footer 153px
or if page height 800px
footer 253px
```

can i do this? i use below code but not work

```
#header{
width:100%;
height:7px;
}
#content{
width:960px;
height:54px;
margin:0 auto 0;
}
    #footer{
        width:100%;
        background-color:#aeb0b3;
        height:100%;
        position: relative;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

Comment: check out CSS media-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worry about IE8 browsers, then you can use `calc` function in CSS.

```
  #footer{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#aeb0b3;
    height:calc(100% - 547px);
    position: relative;
    bottom:0;
   }
```

I hope you have already set body and html element with width and height as 100% like below.

```
 body, html{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

[**Sample DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jS5AP/)